# Why Selenium method get(), doesnt work second time?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Help me figure out why when using the get () method a second time, the page does not go? The method works only if you use a time delay time.sleep ()

Not working:

```
LOGIN = 'something@mail.com'
PASS = 'somepass'
LINK = 'https://stepik.org/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(LINK)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.find_element_by_id('ember232').click()
username = browser.find_element_by_name('login').send_keys(LOGIN)
pas = browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(PASS)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type = "submit"]').click()
browser.get('https://stepik.org/lesson/237240/step/3?unit=209628')
```

Working

```
LOGIN = 'something@mail.com'
PASS = 'somepass'
LINK = 'https://stepik.org/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(LINK)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.find_element_by_id('ember232').click()
username = browser.find_element_by_name('login').send_keys(LOGIN)
pas = browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(PASS)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type = "submit"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get('https://stepik.org/lesson/237240/step/3?unit=209628')
```

Comment: You need to wait for the browser to write cookies after you login.  If you send a get, you'll interrupt that process and the browser/server will abandon the previous login request.  (So the 2nd get is always working... but if you don't wait for the login process to complete, you are not logged in and it sounds like this site is redirecting you back to the login page... and you've already go that cached.)

Comment: an efficient way to wait is to check for an expected condition that appears after the browser has written the cookies.  (generally they will either update the DOM, or redirect... so use a webdriverwait to check the DOM for whatever indicates that you are logged in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to login into the web site and then to navigate to some internal page.
By clicking the submit button

```
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type = "submit"]').click()
```

You are trying to log into the site.
This process takes some time.
So if immediately after clicking the submit page, while login is still not proceed, you are trying to navigate to some internal page this will not work since you still not logged in.
However you do not need to use a hardcoded sleep of 5 seconds.
You can use an explicit wait of expected conditions like `presence_of_element_located()` of some internal element to indicate you are inside the web site. Once this condition is fulfilled you can navigate to the desired internal page.

Comment: Thx. Why implicite waits doesnt working? I used it.                                      
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

Comment: `implicitly_wait` is setting a selenium timeout to find elements. By default this value is set to 0 so in case you will use something like `browser.find_element_by_id('ember232').click()` immediately after `browser.get(LINK)` it will fail since it takes some time to make elements to be loaded. So with `browser.implicitly_wait(5)
` selenium will pool the DOM ut to 5 seconds to find element matching id=ember232. But this is definitely NOT a pause command.

Comment: Prophet, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternative way:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://stepik.org/lesson/237240/step/3?unit=209628")
```

Comment: hasn't it already been implemented in python? because this method was implemented on Java.